Formulating a Spatial Analysis Problem as an NP-Hard Reduction
I'm tackling a computational geometry challenge involving an collection of 2D point coordinates, where each point represents a corner of a polygon. Now I want to fill this polygon with as many points as possible. It is important to note that these points all have a minimum distance constraint, which means that none of these points shall be closer together than 10 length units. Given the complexity, I'm interested in a formulation that reduces this to an NP-hard problem to better understand its computational limits and possibly apply known heuristics or approximation algorithms. Any insights or suggestions on how to approach this would be greatly appreciated!
